# Autocmd popup menu

Tags: vim, vi

I am not asking for plugins. I want to know how can I trigger the pop up menu after inserting every character. In other words is it possible to press `ctrl+n` automatically after every character inserted like in IDE.(to show Possible Mathes)

```
autocmd CursorHoldI * call Pop()

function! Pop()
normal! <c-n>
endfunction
```

but this code doesn't work.

Comment: `:help complete()`

Comment: For the second argument where can I find the normal list autocompletion.

Comment: There's no such thing; you must build that list yourself. If you want to be the one millionth person to re-implement autocompletion in Vim, take a look at existing solutions like https://gist.github.com/maxboisvert/a63e96a67d0a83d71e9f49af73e71d93#file-vimrc-L15

Comment: Thanks @romainl the solution was `feedkeys()` function.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the function `feedkeys()` as below:

```
set completeopt+=noinsert
autocmd CursorHoldI * call feedkeys("\<c-n>")
```